# Does Solaris ipfilter simply stop filtering if it is not running?

Tags: networking, solaris, access-control-list

There is a service for ipfilter which can be disabled or enabled. However, I am concerned that ipfilter might be a processes which would stop filtering if it was killed, crashed or otherwise not running. Is this just the way it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other Solaris service, ipfilter will be automatically restarted if killed or in the unlikely event it crashes. However, the userland part of ipfilter is only composed of monitoring tools (ipmon and svc.ipfd). The filtering logic is in the Solaris kernel so cannot crash or be killed (outside a system panic or shutdown).

Answer (score 1):

It's loaded into the kernel.  It's actually not Solaris but an open source project:

http://coombs.anu.edu.au/~avalon/ip-filter.html

Comment: ipfilter is definely part of Solaris, like many other Open Source projects.

Comment: It's included in Solaris.  It's not part of the Solaris code.  It's available on a variety of OSes.

Comment: Ipfilter is indeed an Open Source project but you are missing the question is about ipfilter as implemented as a Solaris service. This part is definitely Solaris specific. eg:  http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/ipf/svc/ipfd.c . In any case, ipfilter is part of Solaris code too. eg: http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/inet/ipf/fil.c

Comment: I only added that because as far documentation it's easier to go the project site rather than look for it in Solaris docs.  To the original question, because it's documented as a kernel module on that project page, there's no process to die.

Answer (score 1):

The ipfilter SMF service takes care of a few things:

- Load/unload firewall rules
- Load/unload IPFilter kernel module
- Start/stop monitoring tools (eg. ipmon)

You can get the service manifest with:

```
svccfg export ipfilter
```

The script that does all the work is: /lib/svc/method/ipfilter

Here is an example:

```
# svcs -a | grep ipfilter
disabled       20:52:09 svc:/network/ipfilter:default
# grep -v \# /etc/ipf/ipf.conf
pass in from any to any
# modinfo | grep ipf
# svcadm enable ipfilter
# modinfo | grep ipf
229 f9b3f000  24238 165   1  ipf (IP Filter: v4.1.9)
# ipfstat -io
empty list for ipfilter(out)
pass in from any to any
# svcadm disable ipfilter
# modinfo | grep ipf
# ipfstat -io
empty list for ipfilter(out)
empty list for ipfilter(in)
```

If you want IP filtering to work, make sure the IPFilter SMF service is enabled and /etc/ipf/ipf.conf has all the necessary rules.